# When does a program appear under the "How do you want to open this file?" list?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Under Windows 10, when hitting "open with..." you are prompted with a list of programs that Windows suggests.

My question, how does a program end up there? Is it like a parameter that the developer sets? Or is it Windows that checks if the program fulfills certain requirements? Or perhaps it lists the most frequently run programs in general?

Comment: Its something in the registry. If you create a file association, either using the Open with.. and browse for another program, or you use the registry itself, it will be available for Open With... Once it is available there, you can also go to Settings and set it as default app there.

Comment: An application is added either by the application making the required changes to your file association or due to the fact the user selected an application from the list of "other" applications.  In either case, the appropriate registry keys are created, allowing the application to be assigned as the default application for the extension in question.

Comment: i know its in the registry, ive used that in the past to set programms for file endings, but i wonder if thats something that devs themself manually do? because i once saw an occassion where windows prompted to open something like a pdf? with a game (i think it was CSGO or something), and that didnt really make sense